# Table with one large image and text rows

Tags: tables, graphics, text

I am trying to convert a table from MS Word to LaTeX that contains a large image at the first column and several lines of text on the right-hand side. As a beginner, I have no idea how I can achieve this. I am using 2 column document. Can it be contained within one column?

[image]

Please help.

EDIT:
Although I could not do it but I am providing the MWE for my document to give an idea of what packages I am using already.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%Table packages
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
% just a random table from this article

% System Components
\begin{table}
% table caption is above the table
\caption{Hardware components and specifications}
\label{tab:2}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{tabularx}
                {\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1in}
                            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1in}
                             X
                             }
\toprule
\thead{Component} &\thead{ Hardware\\specification} & \thead{Architecture\\application}\\
\midrule\\
\textbf{Android Mobile} & Redmi 4A with Android 8.0, 2GB RAM, 16GB ROM & Client device for data acquisition  \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Processing and monitoring Unit} & Raspberry Pi 4 with 4GB RAM on latest Raspbian OS (December 2020)   &  Main processing unit that runs all the algorithms.\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Wi-Fi Router(Optional)} & Mi Band-3 high speed router with 70 Mbps Broadband connection & The communication hub for the architecture in indoor monitoring.\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end {document}
```

Source image
[image]

Comment: Difficult. To us are unknown image size, document layout ... What you try so far? Image can be inserted in multirow cell.

Comment: The image and the text that is shown in the OP is the actual one. The same image can be reused. Usually, I do not ask for help without trying and providing the MWC of my trial. But this time I have no idea where to start. Similar posts deal with text and image in 1:1 ratio. So they are not really helping.

Comment: A MWE that at least shows the documentclass you currently use as well as the code that produces the table would be really helpful here.

Comment: I have added MWE of another table to show the working environment as per leandriis suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of `tabularx` for table was correct way ...

After small tweaks it can be obtain the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%Table packages
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}% new

\usepackage{lipsum} % new, for dummy text filler

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Hardware components and specifications}
\label{tab:2}
    \small
    \sisetup{product-units = single}
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\hsize=1.1\hsize}X  
                             @{\quad}l 
                                >{\hsize=0.9\hsize}L @{}}
    \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-3}
\multirow{22}{=}{\includegraphics[height=22\baselineskip,
                                  width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}
    &  Model
        &   \thead[l]{Xiaomi Redmi 4a}                      \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
     & OS           & Android~8.0                           \\
     & Size         & \SI{14 x 0.9 x 7}{\centi\meter}       \\
     & CPU          & \SI{1.4}{\giga\hertz} Qualcomm Snapdragon~425 64-bit Cortex~A53 quad core processor           \\
     & RAM/ROM      & \SI{3}{\giga B}/\SI{32}{\giga B} \\
     & Resolution   & \SI{1280 x 720}{pixels} resolution and \SI{296}{pixel} density        \\
     & Connectivity & Wi-Fi~802.11~b/g/n, Bluetooth~4.0     \\
     & Sensor       & on board BMI160 accelerometer         \\
     & Weight       & \SI{132}{\gram}                       \\
     & Battery      & \SI{3120}{\milli\ampere}              \\
     & GPS          & A-GPS, Glonass                        \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

As you can see from MWE, in comparison to your MWE the following changes/tweaks is done:

- for units is used `siunitx` package
- table use `\small` font size
- removed are vertical lines and the most of horizontales (that table has more "professional `looks`
- to each rows is inserted vertical paddings of 2pt by use of `makegapedcells` defined in the `makecell` package
- test in the last two columns are left aligned

Comment: Thank you Zarko, with a little trial and error with the size specification of your code, I could get almost like the picture in OP. It was impossible for me at my current learning stage to produce such code. Maybe one day I will also be able to do such a level of coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `multirow` package and the `\multirow` command it provides. In the following, I've also used `\makecell` from the `makecell` package to easily add linebreaks to cells in the `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|}
    \cline{2-3}
    \multirow{11}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=0.67]{example-image-9x16}}
     &     Model     &                              \textbf{Xiaomi Redmi~4a}                               \\
    \cline{2-3}
     &      OS       &                                     Android~8.0                                     \\
    \cline{2-3}
     &     Size      &                             $14 \times 0.9 \times 7$ cm                             \\
    \cline{2-3}
     &      CPU      & \makecell{1.4~GHz Qualcomm\\Snapdragon~425 64-bit\\Cortex~A53 quad core\\processor} \\
    \cline{2-3}
     & RAM\slash ROM &                                  3~GB\slash 32 GB                                   \\
    \cline{2-3}
     &  Resolution   &       \makecell{$1280 \times 720$ pixels\\resolution and 296\\pixel density}        \\
    \cline{2-3}
     & Connectivity  &                    \makecell{Wi-Fi~802.11~b/g/n,\\Bluetooth~4.0}                    \\
    \cline{2-3}
     &    Sensor     &                      \makecell{ON BOARD BMI160\\ACCELEROMETER}                      \\
    \cline{2-3}
     &    Weight     &                                      132~Grams                                      \\
    \cline{2-3}
     &    Battery    &                                       3120~mA                                       \\
    \cline{2-3}
     &      GPS      &                                   A-GPS, Glonass                                    \\
    \cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure whether the table really looks all that good with all those horizontal/vertical lines, BTW --- YMMV of course. Usually I recommend the `booktabs` package and its `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\cmidrule` and `\bottomrule` commands, but those tend to produce tables that look like they're straight out of scientific articles (which is great if that's what you're actually writing, of course).

Comment: It is overflowing to the second column. I have added the source image and MWE (of another table), see if it helps. There is no need to have internal grids if it does not look good. I am writing a technical document only.

Comment: I see --- try using `table*` instead of `table`, that should span both columns.

Comment: Spanning it to both columns will mess up with the existing document structure, which as a novice, will be impossible for me to re-arrange( it is in page 7 of a 13 page document). Can it be accommodated within one column by reducing the font size? Pardon my ignorance, I am just a beginner.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "messing up the document structure" or what you mean by "re-arranging". `table`s are floating environments, whether you have one spanning two columns or just one; LaTeX will try to figure out where to best place them. If you want something *right there* your best bet is to not use a `table`at all (you can still use a `tabular` of course!).

Comment: Re: making things fit, if you absolutely must have the table (i.e. the `tabular`, not the `table`) in a column, then yes, you can switch to a smaller font. I have little experience with this, but see e.g. https://latexref.xyz/Font-sizes.html#Font-sizes . I would suggest taking a step back and asking yourself whether it's really necessary to have a table *right there* and within a single column though.